# React functional component - is it possible to pass props to { children }?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-props, react-functional-component

Workaround at the bottom of the question.

I am trying to pass props down to a child component using {children}.

The Father component:

```
const FatherComp = ({ children, propsToPassToChild }) => (
    <div>Dynamic component content: 
        {children}
    </div>
)
```

The child component:

```
const ChildComp = ({ childProps }) => <p>This is the dynamic content</p>
```

Using them like so:

```
<FatherComp>
    <ChildComp/> // childProps cannot be passed here since it's inside FatherComp
</FatherComp>
```

I want to pass to the ChildComp the props (propsToPassToChild ) from the FatherComp directly:

```
const FatherComp = ({ children, propsToPassToChild }) => (
    <div>Dynamic component content: 
        >>>>> {children} <<<<< *passing the props somewhere here* 
    </div>
)
```

Is it possible to achive what I am trying to do with react functional components directly and without state management?

Thanks!

************ My solution ***********

So after a little while in a different project I came accross the same question and I found out a solution.

```
const Father = ({ child }) => {
    return (
        <div>
            {child({ text: 'I am props from father' })}
        </div>
    );
};

const Child = ({ text }) => {
    return (
        <div>Hey there {text}</div>
    );
};
```

and render the Father component:

```
const App = () => <Father child={Child} />
```

Just pass the child in the props of the father as a function that returns a component.
Altough it's not a 'direct' solution this solved the problem without wrapping the child with the father.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `render props`

ref: https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you need to do something like this:

```
<FatherComp>
    <ChildComp name="John" age="21"/>
</FatherComp>

const FatherComp = (props) => (
  <div>Dynamic component content: 
      {props.children}
  </div>
)
```

Accept props in the `FatherComp` and use `{props.children}` to render all the children components inside of your Father component.

Comment: I am trying to pass to props.children another props which Child component accepts

Comment: Can you show us the complete code that you have for anyone of us to understand it better?